# How to determine which logins have sysadmin?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can you determine through T-SQL which logins have sysadmin?

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

-- sysadmin = 1 indicates that the login has sysadmin

SELECT name, dbname DBNAME,sysadmin SYSADMIN, denylogin, isntname, isntgroup, isntuser

FROM master.dbo.syslogins

WHERE sysadmin = 1

Comment: `syslogins` is now deprecated. avoid using it.

Comment: Which version is it deprecated? I am using 2008 - 2017

Comment: All the `dbo.sys*` views are deprecated since version 2005, if memory serves. There are typically similarly named views in the `sys` schema nowadays.